# extracting tuple values from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list containg tuples of different types like:

```
[(0, 1, 'BLANK', ''), (0, 2, 'PERSON', 'Deraj'), (3, 8, 'DOB', 'April 27 , 1834'), (9, 11, 'PERSON', 'David Deraj'), (11, 13, 'LOC', 'Pennsylvania'), (16, 19, 'PERSON', 'Mary Deraj')]
```

How do i get the following output

```
('Deraj', 'David Deraj')
('Deraj', 'Mary Deraj')
```

i am trying to use for loop:

```
for i in l:
    if i[2] == 'PERSON':
        m = list(i[3])
```

but this doesnt work.

Comment: (x[1][3],x[3][3]) and (x[1][3],x[5][3]) should do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can do it like this(if i understand correctly and you want first member of tuple to be second name of those peoples):

```
l=[]
for i in l:
  if i[2]=='PERSON':
      temp=i[3].split()
      if len(temp)>1: 
        l.append((temp[1],i[3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first record `(0, 2, 'PERSON', 'Deraj')` has always the first item zero and the second item indicating the number of family members, you can do this in one line.

```
print [ (entry[3].split()[1], entry[3])
        for entry in data
        if (entry[2] == 'PERSON' and entry[0] > 0) ]
```